# Is it possible to have variable after a loop in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I was wondering is it possible to have variables after a conditions, e.g. when normally a while sentence would be like that:

`$i = 5 
while ($i -le 5) {Write-Host $i; $i++}`

But because I have so many variables in my script I thought may be I could write the variables at the end of the code so I could read the script's logic first not the variables, something like that:

```
while ($i -le 5) {Write-Host $i; $i++}  
$i = 10
$Variable2 = 5
...
$Variable100 = 25
```

Comment: -1 for question that doesn't make any sense. Please rephrase the question, add some examples about desired and occured outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell executes the lines in your script in order from top to bottom except where a loop, condition, or a function call make the execution jump somewhere else.

So, no, you cannot initialise a variable after you used it, that just wouldn't make sense.

Your solution here would be to move all the logic inside one or more functions, and then at the end of your script you can initialise variables and call the function(s). That does roughly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to expressly declare a variable in PowerShell, if that's what you're asking. Variables that weren't defined before are automatically defined and initialized with default value the first time they're used.

However, depending on how the variable is used, you may inadvertently get different variables with the same name in different scopes:

```
PS C:\> function Foo { $i; $i = 23; $i }
PS C:\> Foo
23
PS C:\> $i = 42
PS C:\> $i
42
PS C:\> Foo
42
23
PS C:\> $i
42
PS C:\> function Bar { $i; $global:i = 23; $i }
PS C:\> Bar
42
23
PS C:\> $i
23
```

Also, if you want a variable to start with a specific value, you need to initialize it before you use it. If you have numerous initializations, you could put them into a separate PowerShell script and [dot-source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx#ECAA) that second script in your "worker" script:

```
. 'C:\path\to\config.ps1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my problem was when a variable was after a While sentence it didn't work - said it can't find such variable.

Comment: In that case please update your question with a code sample that actually demonstrates the problem. Also include the exact error message you're getting.